How can I pause a GKE autopilot nigthly?
How can I pause my GKE Autopilot cluster nightly in GCP? This cluster supports the Cloud Composer service in our Data stage area.
We know that it's not possible to do this natively because the service does not support this option, but it is possible to reduce the number of nodes to zero. However, Composer creates an Autopilot cluster in GKE. When we reduce the number of nodes, the service automatically enables new nodes.
We scheduled a job in Cloud Scheduler, created a topic in Pub/Sub, and triggered a Cloud Function in Python to handle the process of pausing and resuming the cluster.
import os
from google.cloud import container_v1
from google.auth import default
from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException

def main(event, context):
    cluster_name = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    location = "xxxxxxxx"
    project_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx"

    print("Autenticando no GKE e obtendo credenciais do cluster...")
    # Authenticate to GKE and get cluster credentials
    credentials, project = default()
    client = container_v1.ClusterManagerClient(credentials=credentials)
    cluster_info = client.get_cluster(name=f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/clusters/{cluster_name}")

    print(f"Conectado ao cluster {cluster_name}.")

    # Configure Kubernetes client
    print("Configurando cliente Kubernetes...")
    config.load_kube_config_from_dict({
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "clusters": [{
            "cluster": {
                "server": "https://" + cluster_info.endpoint,
                "certificate-authority-data": cluster_info.master_auth.cluster_ca_certificate,
            },
            "name": cluster_info.name,
        }],
        "contexts": [{
            "context": {
                "cluster": cluster_info.name,
                "user": "default",
            },
            "name": "default",
        }],
        "current-context": "default",
        "kind": "Config",
        "preferences": {},
        "users": [{
            "name": "default",
            "user": {
                "auth-provider": {
                    "config": {
                        "access-token": credentials.token,
                        "cmd-args": "config config-helper --format=json",
                        "cmd-path": "gcloud",
                        "expiry-key": "{.credential.token_expiry}",
                        "token-key": "{.credential.access_token}",
                    },
                    "name": "gcp",
                },
            },
        }],
    })

    # Scale up all deployments in the default namespace to the original number of replicas
    v1 = client.AppsV1Api()
    deployments = v1.list_namespaced_deployment(namespace='default')
    print("Escalonando todos os deployments para três réplicas...")
    for deployment in deployments.items:
        # You should store the original number of replicas somewhere; here we assume 3 for all
        deployment.spec.replicas = 3
        try:
            v1.patch_namespaced_deployment(
                name=deployment.metadata.name,
                namespace='default',
                body=deployment
            )
            print(f"Deployment {deployment.metadata.name} escalonado para três réplicas")
        except ApiException as e:
            print(f"Exceção ao escalar deployment {deployment.metadata.name}: {e}")

    print("Retomar cluster concluído.")


But it’s not working.
Please, help us!

"it's not working" is not a good example of an issue description. Your code doesn't work as-is and, with some corrections, does not do what you describe. You suggest you want to scale e.g. Deployments to zero but the corrected code scales Deployments (in default Namespace) to three (3).

Why don't you just delete the cluster overnight? Using a corrected version of your code to scale Deployments (in default) to zero does not necessarily "pause" the cluster because there could be other Deployments in other Namespaces and other resources across the cluster.

You may continue to incur control-plane costs for Autopilot as long as clusters are running

My bad, @DazWilkin, I posted the resume code instead of the pause code. The correct code should be something like "deployment.spec.replicas = 0". It's not possible to delete because this cluster was automatically created by the Cloud Composer service. At the end of the day, I need to pause the Composer. If I delete, the configured DAGs will be deleted too. Do you have any suggestions?

I'm unfamiliar with Cloud Composer and unable to comment. When I corrected the code, I used deployment.spec.replicas=0 and this does set Deployments in default to zero. So the behavior is then as you described. However, I'd continue to caution that this may be insufficient to "pause" the cluster.
